# Read and write XML at once

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm reading a portion of an online XML database (example [here](http://api.discogs.com/release/367315)):

```
var release     = XElement.Parse(text).Element("release");
var artist      = release.Element("artists").Element("artist").Element("name").Value;
var albumTitle  = release.Element("title").Value;
var positions   = release.Element("tracklist").Descendants("position").Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
var titles      = release.Element("tracklist").Descendants("title").Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

This works well, but now I want to write these variables into a local XML file, with this structure:

```
<releases>
    <release>
        <artist></artist>
        <albumTitle></albumTitle>
        <tracklist>
            <track>
                <position></position>
                <title></title>
            </track>
        </tracklist>
    </release>
</releases>
```

(Note that there must be multiple `track` elements, each containing `position` and `title`.)

I'm wondering how both steps (reading from and writing to XML) can be done at once.

Answer (score 1):

With an assumption that multiple `release`s can exist in `releases`,

usage:

```
List<Release> releases = ......
string xmlString = releases.Save();
```

and

```
List<Release> releases = xmlString.Load();
```

---

```
[XmlType("release")]
public class Release
{
    [XmlElement("artist")]
    public string Artist { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("albumTitle")]
    public string AlbumTitle { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("tracklist")]
    [XmlArrayItem("track")]
    public List<Track> TrackList { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("track")]
public class Track
{
    [XmlElement("position")]
    public string Position { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static List<Release> Load(this string xmlStr)
    {
        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlStr))
        {
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Release>), new XmlRootAttribute("releases"));
            return (List<Release>)xs.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }

    public static string Save(this List<Release> list)
    {
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        namespaces.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);

        using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(writer, settings);

            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Release>), new XmlRootAttribute("releases"));

            xs.Serialize(xmlWriter, list, namespaces);
            return writer.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for how to write XML to a file.  This should point you in the right direction:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw229a22.aspx

The XDocument API allows XElements to be added/modified/deleted, and it also allows the document to be written to disk.